# Unable to change SSL Enable to False in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms, wcf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1mvr.png)

Any Solution for Above Image.
Initially Enable SSL was false I change and build the solution After that I am not able to change.
This is WCF Services.
is there any solution. please share.
Thank you adavance

Answer (score 0):

**Change Project URL**:

Open your Visual Studio project.
Go to the project properties (right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, then select "Properties").
In the properties window, navigate to the "Web" tab or section.
**Adjust Project URL**:

Find the "Project URL" setting. It likely shows an HTTPS URL (https://...).
Change this URL to a non-secure HTTP URL (http://...). Remove the "s" from "https://" to "http://".
**Save Changes**:

After modifying the URL, save the changes to the project properties.
Reconfigure SSL (if needed):

If you need to re-enable SSL later, you can update the project URL back to use HTTPS after resolving the immediate issue.
**Build and Test**:

Rebuild your solution and try running/debugging your web project again to ensure it operates without SSL.

Comment: I got this solution Its Working Fine

Comment: No need to change anything on the configurations. Please follow above steps